# Lengthy base64(more than 3 MB) string in a Post call to WebApi could not be retrieved. I just get null instead of data

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

My Request looks something like this:

User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:12841
Content-Length: 4512954

Inside Body I have--> "*base64encoded String*"

API Controller contains a method :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public bool SaveProductImage([FromBody]string image)
        {
            if(image!=null)
            var result =                         productImageRules.StoreSingleImageOnDisk(image.ToString());            
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: please give more detail

Comment: Itz quite simple...I want to save an image on disk using webapi. So What I am trying to do is, I am sending base64encoded(by converting an image to base64string) string via fiddler/postman to webapi but webapi gets null if the size of the string is more than 3 mbs, for small data it works fine. I have been trying so hard to get rid of this issue but no luck, I could not find any post which could give me answer of this issue

Answer (score 12):

Be sure to allow the application to receive large POSTs in your **web.config**.

Here's an example for **10mb**.

For **ASP.NET**.

```xml
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>
```

For **IIS**

```xml
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: Im also have an issue with this. Ive applied your solution but still the full image does not upload as base64. only a part of the image. As im using a shared web farm hosting service can the hosting service be overriding this setting?

Comment: Yes it's probable, try locally first to test.

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution.
in your web.config(in server)

```
----------
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
     <standardEndpoints>           
    <webHttpEndpoint>
 <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" /> 
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>

----------
<system.web.extensions> 
   <scripting> 
      <webServices> 
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/> 
      </webServices> 
   </scripting> 
</system.web.extensions> 
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097151"     useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"     executionTimeout="14400"  />
----------
<system.webServer>
    <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
----------
```

good look

Answer (score 0):

I fix it using this in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
```